# Why i cant see my balance in geth

Tags: go-ethereum

I used that command for install my node

geth console --rinkeby --datadir=~/.gophersland_ethereum_r1 --port=30304 --cache=6048 --rpc --rpcport=8546 --rpcapi=eth,web3,net,personal syncmode=fast

After i created one wallet and transfer some quantity of ethereum for this wallet.
But, when i execute the command "eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[0])" the result is always 0.

But, if i checked the balance in etherscan the balance appears right.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Most likely you are not synchronized with the network

Comment: I went to consult the block and the number of block is "3880458". Is it so time consuming to synchronize?